# Homebrew Can't Find LFTP Formula on macOS Sierra

Tags: homebrew, lftp, macos-sierra

I just upgraded to macOS Sierra and installed brew to get some packages. Previously I used [LFTP](http://brewformulas.org/Lftp) to sync files from a remote server more quickly. However, after upgrading to Sierra, brew can no longer install LFTP. After using

```
brew install lftp
```

I get the following output and error

```
Checking out v1.0.1 in /usr/local/Homebrew...
To checkout v1.0.1 in /usr/local/Homebrew run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git checkout v1.0.1
Error: No available formula with the name "lftp" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
This similarly named formula was found:
homebrew/x11/curlftpfs ✔
To install it, run:
  brew install homebrew/x11/curlftpfs ✔
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I believe it cannot find the formula... but I'm not sure why. Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a patch now. lftp is back again and moved from boneyard to mainstream: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/2c0e087580bafde50c916ad304ffb2079f593b7e

A simple `brew install lftp` will work again.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like lftp was moved to the boneyard. I still have it installed and it was found in `homebrew/boneyard/lftp`. Not sure why that happened though. I don't think it's a macOS Sierra related problem, just unfortunate timing.

Comment: It was [moved to the boneyard](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/pull/161) apparently because of [build breakage around openssl](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/1509) and unenthusiastic upstream support for MacOS.  Which is a shame because it's a nice tool.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the reason it was moved @poolie :)

Comment: This was it. Thanks for the input. You have to install from the boneyard with `brew install homebrew/boneyard/lftp`. I thought I already replied to this thread but apparently it didn't register my reply a few days back.

Comment: It looks like the entire site which was hosting lftp now is down, and it's not even accessible through the boneyard. Got this error message: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to lftp.yar.ru port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: It's back up in the boneyard. I just installed it today.

Comment: I get an error: ``curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html``

Answer (score 4):

one solution, if you're ok with using the latest stable release as of this writing, is to install lftp (4.6.6) from the boneyard:

`brew install homebrew/boneyard/lftp`

as @Sebastian and @poolie pointed out, [lftp has been moved to the boneyard](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/4956).